# Can't unwrap optional when calling a global class

Tags: swift, ios8

I have the following code in one of my classes.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    parkCode = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).text

    RTATab.codeText.text = parkCode.substringToIndex(3) 
    RTATab.codeLetter.text = parkCode.substringFromIndex(3)
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

The `RTATab` referenced above is another class I have made (type `UIViewController`) and in that class I have declared it as a global class as show below as I need to access some of the textfields (`codeText` and `codeLetter`) in its view.

```
import UIKit
import messageUI
import CoreData
import QuartzCore

var RTATab : ViewController = ViewController()

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    //some code
}
```

When I run this, I get a `can't unwrap optional.none` error on the line `RTATab.codeText.text = parkCode.substringToIndex(3)`.

Can someone please help. Do I need to have an initialiser in viewController class?

Thanks

Comment: How is parkCode defined?

Comment: It is non-idiomatic to name variables, specifically 'RTATab', with an initial capital letter; capitals are 'reserved' for types.  It makes your use of 'RTATab.codeText' look like a reference to a class variable.

Comment: parkCode is defined as var parkCode :NSString? = "no Code"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error the text of the cell is `nil`. Before calling methods on parkCode, you must first check if it is nil:

```
let possibleParkCode = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).text
if let parkCode = possibleParkCode {
    RTATab.codeText.text = parkCode.substringToIndex(3) 
    RTATab.codeLetter.text = parkCode.substringFromIndex(3)
}
```

Comment: Didnt work. When I do println, the values are shown. So not sure where this error is being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Either `parkCode` or `RTATab.codeText` don't exist (are `nil`).  You need to check for their existence prior to dereferencing either of them.

```
override func tableView (tableView: ...) {
  if let theParkCode = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).text {
    parkCode = theParkCode;
    if let theCodeText = RTATab.codeText {
       theCodeText.text = parkCode?.substringToIndex(3)
    }
    if let theCodeLetter ... {
    // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the above code depends on how your `ViewController` (the class of `RTATab`) declares its instance variables for `codeText` and `codeLetter` - I've assumed as optionals.

Comment: The codeLetter is declared as : "@IBOutlet var codeLetter: UITextField". When I do a println statement, parkCode does show a value. Means it is not nil correct? Tried the if statements as above and the code within does get executed. However when I try to assign to textfield, gives me same error. So basically, assigning to another variable works but when to text field it gives me cant unwrap error.

Comment: The type of `parkCore` is `String?` - you said that earlier.  I updated my code to replace `parkCode.substringToIndex(3)` with `parkCode?.substringToIndex(3)`.  Or, instead of using the optional `parkCode` you could just use the non-optional `theParkCode`.

Comment: I have tried this as well however I cannot catch the nil. It does go into the if statement. When I println, the values show as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because `RTATab.codeText` and `RTATab.codeLetter` are `nil` -- the way you're initializing `RTATab` doesn't actually link up its properties with the text fields in your storyboard. If you truly just need a global version of the view controller, you'd need to give it a storyboard ID and load it using something like:

```
var RTATab: ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RTA") as ViewController
```

However, my guess is that it's a view controller you've already displayed elsewhere that you want to update, in which case you're better off just setting up a data structure that can hold the "parkCode" values and pulling them back into the correct view controller when it's time to display them.

Comment: Yes I am sending back the data to another view controller and updating the textfield. Now I have created a struct in that view controller and am able to pass the data however when I try to use the values to update the textfield, it gives me the same error on the line I use the text field...any idea?